# SUMIFs for all the rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I am trying to replicate SUMIFs in Python that I have in my excel by creating a new column called SumifsZ. SumifsZ is the desired output i would need in python.

my formula in first row of SumifsZ column is =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"Z",A:A,A2) , i would need that to be replicated in 3rd,4th rows.... etc.

| Product | Region | QTY | SumifZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 3 | 13 |
| A | Z | 3 | 13 |
| B | Z | 9 | 9 |
| B | X | 2 | 9 |
| C | Y | 5 | 0 |
| A | Z | 10 | 13 |
| D | Z | 11 | 20 |
| D | Z | 9 | 20 |
| E | Y | 6 | 0 |
| F | Z | 7 | 7 |

the code i am using is `Data['SumifsZ'] = Data.query('Region =="Z"').QTY.sum()`

and i am not getting the same result as excel. please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: What is `Data`? A Pandas DataFrame? Please edit to clarify that, add the Pandas tag, and show how you're creating it. For more tips, [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) and [mre] in general.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

---

You can approach this problem by slicing the data frame with `loc` and using `groupby` on "Product". This can be converted to a `dict` and used in a lambda function via `apply` as follows:

```
Data = pd.DataFrame({"Product":["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "D", "D", "E", "F"],
                    "Region":["X", "Z", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Y", "Z"],
                    "QTY":[3, 3, 9, 2, 5, 10, 11, 9, 6, 7]})


Zmap = Data.loc[Data.Region=='Z',:].groupby('Product').sum().to_dict()['QTY']

Data.loc[:,'SumifZ'] = Data.Product.apply(lambda x: Zmap[x] if x in Zmap.keys() else 0)
```

**Result:**

```
    Product Region  QTY SumifZ
0   A   X   3   13
1   A   Z   3   13
2   B   Z   9   9
3   B   X   2   9
4   C   Y   5   0
5   A   Z   10  13
6   D   Z   11  20
7   D   Z   9   20
8   E   Y   6   0
9   F   Z   7   7
```

---

*Docs:*

- [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. SumifZ is the desired coulmn. it is not a part of dataframe.

Comment: my current excel formula in first row of SUMIFZ column is  =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"Z",A:A,A2) which will be replicated to other rows for A3,A4 ... etc.

Comment: @Nandishvk27 Sorry it took so long for me to get back to this, I have edited the previous answer with the understanding that `SumifZ` is the column to be created. I hope this helps.